# Problema ao fazer a paginação em jQuery e Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, paginação

Estou montando uma paginação e estou com o seguinte problema.

Primeiramente os meus botões próximo e anterior não estão funcionando e não mostra nenhum erro no console.

A segunda questão é que, quando eu seleciono no combo box, o valor de itens por página ele traz os itens do valor selecionado no combo mas o estranho é que ele altera o label que mostraria a página Página 3 de 1     Página 4 de 1 e assim sucessivamente.

ALguém pode me ajudar ?

meu html

```
<div >

    <div class=" jPager"> 

            <div class="input-group  col-lg-3  col-md-3  col-sm-3 col-xs-12 pull-left">
                    <select onchange="carregarDistritos()" id="idSelecionaSize" class="form-control" data-pager-action='pagesize'>
                            <option value="5">Ver 5</option>
                            <option value="15">Ver 15</option>
                            <option value="20">Ver 20</option>
                            <option value="25">Ver 25</option>
                            <option value="50">Ver 50</option>
                            <option value="100">Ver 100</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            <div class="input-group   col-lg-6  col-md-6  col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <button  class="btn btn-default id="anterior" >&lsaquo; Anterior</button>
                                <span id="numeracao"></span>
                        <button  class="btn btn-default id="proximo" >Próximo &rsaquo;</button>
                            </div>


                        </div>

                    </div>
```

A resposta do meu get vindo da API é a seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

meu JS

```
app.controller("buscaDistritoController", function($scope,  $http, $location) {



    $scope.distritos = [];
    $scope.distrito = {}; // binding com o form

    carregarDistritos = function() {
        token = localStorage.getItem("userToken");

        var e = document.getElementById("idSelecionaSize");
        var size = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;


        var page=0;

        var search = $location.search();
        var page = search.page||page;
        var size = search.size||size;
        var sort = search.sort||'type,desc';


        $http({
             method: 'GET',
             url: '/user/distritosPaginacao?page=' + page + '&size=' + size + '&sort=' + sort
        }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.distritos = response.data.content;
            $scope.number= response.data.number;
            $scope.page = response.data.totalPages;
            $scope.sort = sort;


            paginar = function() {
                $('table > tbody > tr').remove();
                var tbody = $('table > tbody');
                for (var i = $scope.page * size; i < $scope.distritos.length && i < ($scope.page + 1) *  size; i++) {
                    tbody.append(
                        $('<tr>')
                            .append($('<td>').append(dados[i][0]))
                            .append($('<td>').append(dados[i][1]))
                    )
                }
                $('#numeracao').text('Página ' + ($scope.page + 1) + ' de ' + Math.ceil($scope.distritos.length / size));
            }

            ajustarBotoes = function() {
                $('#proximo').prop('disabled', $scope.distritos.length <= size || $scope.page >= Math.ceil($scope.distritos.length / size) - 1);
                $('#anterior').prop('disabled', $scope.distritos.length <= size || $scope.page == 0);
            }

            $(function() {
                $('#proximo').click(function() {
                    if (size < $scope.distritos.length / size - 1) {
                        $scope.page++;
                        paginar();
                        ajustarBotoes();
                    }
                });
                $('#anterior').click(function() {
                    if ($scope.page > 0) {
                        $scope.page--;
                        paginar();
                        ajustarBotoes();
                    }
                });
                paginar();
                ajustarBotoes();
            });


        }, function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log(response.status);
        });

    }; 
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Velho, você não poderia usar o [UI Boostrap Pagination](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#pagination)? Acredito que seria muito mais simples. Segue um exemplo:

```
<ul uib-pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="5"class="pagination-sm" boundary-links="true" num-pages="numPages" ng-change="pageChanged()" first-text="Primeiro" last-text="Último" next-text="Próximo" previous-text="Anterior"></ul>
```

No seu js ficaria assim:

```
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.pageChanged = function () {        
    $http.post('carregarDistritos', { skip: $scope.currentPage })
        .then(function success(response) {                
            $scope.totalItems = response.data.total;
            $scope.distritos = response.data.listDistritos                                
        }, function error(response) {
    alert('Ops! Um erro aconteceu ao buscar os dados.')});
}
```

Ao navegar pelos botões da paginação você terá a numeração da página selecionada no $scope.currentPage, assim basta fazer o skip e take caso você use expressão LINQ.

Não sei se é o que você precisa, mas é um forma simples e muito útil de fazer paginação e outra opção.